# Is there any way I can set a custom DNS for an Azure Function when running locally?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am creating a set of Azure Function (v2.x, C#, .Net Core).

I am using the Azure Tools to run it locally.

I have found how to specify custom ports when running the functions but now I need to have specific domain names for each function when running locally.

This is so I can configure one function to call another one by it's domain name and later configure that as an App Setting when deploying.

Is there a way to do this? or this is not the right approach when working with Azure functions and I have to use something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding some entry on your local hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Comment: assuming it's http trigger, you can create an entry on your hosts pointing customdns to 127.0.0.1 in your browser rather than localhost you use the customdns entry you've created.